# How to apply a where clause to every result on a joined table?

Tags: sql

This is a simplified version of my table structure:

[image]

I'm trying to get a list of replays where every player in it has the same skill.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM "Replay" R
JOIN "Team" T ON R.id = T."replayId"
JOIN "Player" P ON T.id = P."teamId"
WHERE P."skill" = 2
```

However, this returns replays where at least only one person has skill 2, even if the rest of the players have different skills, and I need it to match for every player in the replay. Any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation.
In your query you must group by `Replay.id` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT R.id 
FROM Replay R
JOIN Team T ON R.id = T.replayId
JOIN Player P ON T.id = P.teamId
GROUP BY R.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN P.skill = 2 THEN 1 END)
```

The condition `COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN P.skill = 2 THEN 1 END)` makes sure than only the replays where all rows have `skill = 2` will be returned.

Comment: Awesome! this seems to return the right data. is there a way I can select all the fields using this?

Comment: @Jazcash if your database supports `SELECT * ...` with GROUP BY then just make the change. If not, use `SELECT * FROM Replay WHERE id IN (<the query here>)`.

Answer (score 1):

another options is the NOT IN condition by excluding all the teams where at least one player hasn't got skill 2:

```
SELECT * FROM "Replay" R
JOIN "Team" T ON R.id = T."replayId"
JOIN "Player" P ON T.id = P."teamId"
WHERE P."skill" = 2
where T."teamId" not in
(select "teamId" from "Player" where "skill" <> 2)
```